# Powershell URI builder for a sys admin

Tags: powershell

Forgive my ignorance - I am trying to write a powershell cmdlet which takes user input and builds a query uri to an API (one mandatory, 3 opts) - I have kind of got the general idea that I need to use hash tables for dictionary of query strings and parameters.

I'm trying to build `$baseurl + $querystring + '=' + $parameter + '&' + $querystring + '=' $value (if not null)`

e.g. `https://example.com/api?param1=value&param2=value`

so far - and this is very rough, and completely not working:

```
            Function Get-commonURI{ #takes 4 params from user
                [CmdletBinding()]
                Param(
                    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                                ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]

                                [String[]]$value1

                                [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                                ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]

                                [String[]]$value2,
                                [String[]]$value3,
                                [String[]]$value4 

                ) #end param 
            }
        #put the input into a paramter hash table with the query strings

        $Parameters = @{
            query = 'querysting1', 'querystring2', 'querystring3', 'querystring4'
            values = $value1,$value2.$value2, $value4
        }

        uri = https://example.com/api?

    $HttpValueCollection = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString([String]::Empty)

    foreach ($Item in $Parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
#I want to append each query passed in on the cli

foreach ($Value in $Item.Value) {
      $ParameterName = $Item.value

      $HttpValueCollection.Add($ParameterName, $Value)}

$Request  = [System.UriBuilder]($Uri)
$Request.Query = $HttpValueCollection.ToString()

invoke-webrequest $Request.Uri

}
```

I have something like that written but it's not working - am I even on the right track here? - I'm sure this has been done a million times but don't even know what to google - something tells me I shouldn't set up the hash table with variables. thanks for looking.

Comment: Hi, your code does not run _as-is_, and is not well indented so it is hard to read and understand. Can you please try to fix it a bit? For example, I think the first closing curly bracket is misplaced because it ends the function declaration block. I'm afraid I'll break your logic if I try to change things. Also, if you want to take user input, you can try with: `$userValue1 = Read-Host "enter first value"` for instance.

Comment: thanks sodawillow, I'm just trying to get an idea of how to build the query string using hash table - not really looking for code per se, I want to build it as a cmdlet so users can tab out the parameters rather than being prompted so `get-commonURI -param1 value` and `get-commonURI -param1 value param2 value` the cmdlet should build the correct uri

Answer (score 17):

I'm always a fan of not re-inventing the wheel:

```
$ub = new-object System.UriBuilder -argumentlist 'http', 'myhost.com', 80, 'mypath/query.aspx', '?param=value'
$ub.Uri.AbsoluteUri
>>>> http://myhost.com/mypath/query.aspx?param=value
```

Update:

This is a built-in .NET class which has numerous constructors.  The one above accepts a protocol, host, port number, path and query string.  It seems to handle an empty or null query string, so no need to handle this yourself.  For info, the class' constructor can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx).  In order to retrieve input from the user, you can use Read-Host, e.g.:

```
[String] $Local:strServer = '';
[String] $Local:strPath   = '';
[String] $Local:strQuery  = '';
[String] $Local:strUri    = '';

while ( $strServer -eq '' ) {
    $strServer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a server name';
    } #while
while ( $strPath -eq '' ) {
    $strPath   = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a path';
    } #while

# Get query string and ensure it begins with a "?".
$strQuery  = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter a query string';
if ( ($strQuery -ne '') -and (! $strQuery.StartsWith('?')) ) { $strQuery = '?' + $strQuery; } 

try {
    $strUri = [System.UriBuilder]::new( 'http', $strServer, 80, $strPath, $strQuery );
    Write-Host -Object ( 'URI is {0}' -f $strUri );
    } #try
catch [System.ArgumentException] {
    # Something went wrong.
    } #catch
```

Comment: thanks Simon, can you elaborate on it a bit, especially with regard to user input and not appending the query string if the parameter is null. thanks.

Comment: nice one thanks, on a Mac right now but will try this tomorrow and let you know, will accept the answer once I get it a try! thanks again.

Comment: `Method invocation failed because [System.UriBuilder] does not contain a method named 'new'` That isn't how you construct .NET objects in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I wrote this as a cmdlet that takes pipeline input and can be invoked from other scripts - it can open the uri in a browser, save the xml as a document, or cast the document as an xml type object - which is very handy as you can then select the xml object properties (xml nodes, attributes) using dotted notation instead of xPath and Powershells intellisense uses tab completion so you can cycle thru the xml nodes on the command line or in the Powershell ISE.

I also use the powershell community extensions module 
https://pscx.codeplex.com/ for it's sensible join-string cmdlet.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
$authparam = '&auth='
$baseURI = 'https://example.com/restapi?'
$password = 'plaintextpassword'

Function Get-APICommon
{
    #takes 4 params and auth key
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   ValueFromPipeline = $true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [String[]]$param1,
        [String[]]$Param2,
        [String[]]$Param3,
        [String[]]$Param4

    ) #end param 

    Begin { }
    process
    {

        $Parameters = [ordered] @{
            Query1 = $Param1
            Query2 = $Param2
            Query3 = $Param3
            Query4 = $Param4
        }
        #This particular API needs to have query parameters separated by ':' and hashed as part of the authentication parameter i.e param1:param2:param3:param4:password
        $preauth = ($Parameters.GetEnumerator() | % { "$($_.Value)" }) -join ':'

        $prehash = Join-String $preauth, ':', $password
        $hash = $prehash | Get-Hash -Algorithm SHA1 -StringEncoding ascii


        foreach ($item in $Parameters.GetEnumerator())
        {

            if ($item.value -ne $null)
            {

                $query =[System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($uriBuilder.Query)
                $query[$item.key] = $item.Value

                $uriBuilder = [System.UriBuilder]::new($baseURI)
                $uriBuilder.Query = $query.ToString()
                $baseURI = $uriBuilder.ToString()
            }



        }

        $queryURI = Join-String $baseURI, $authparam, $hash
        Write-Host $queryURI


    $Resultfile = Join-String $($Parameters.Query1),'-Result.xml'

    $Resultxml = [xml](Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $queryURI | Select-Object -ExpandProperty content | Out-File $Resultfile)

    $Parameters.Clear()


        $Browser = new-object -com internetexplorer.application

        $Browser.navigate2("$queryURI")

        $Browser.visible = $true


    }


}
```

Example usage

get-APICommon -param1 querystring

or

get-APICommon -param1 queryvalue1 -param2 queryvalue2

example results

```
https://example.com/restapi?&query1=queryvalue&query2=queryvalue2&auth=JSJAUJQJALF09OLQLS34LLK
```

Answer (score 0):

The `System.UriBuilder` class is no-frills when it comes to adding query parameters. For anything but the simplest queries this shoves all the complexity of query generation into your code, which can quickly turn it into spaghetti. Fortunately, Powershell classes allow us to extend `System.UriBuilder` to handle the complexity for us.

List of things this class provides:

- Automatically escapes the `value` part of the key/value pair.
- Enables the addition of multiple parameters with the same key. Consider that other, pure hashtable solutions, may not account for this use case and that hashtables do not allow duplicate keys.
- Enables conversion of an array of values into a string, joined by choice of char/string, for `value` part of the key/value pair.
- Enables addition of parameters only when a given constant/scriptblock evaluates to true.

Examples can be found in the comment header.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Updated version of the System.UriBuilder class with improved support for query params.
.DESCRIPTION
    Version of the UriBuilder class with improved support for Query Params.

    Provides the following benefits over the base class:
      * Automatically escapes the value part of the key/value pair.

      * Enables the addition of multiple parameters with the same key.
        Consider that other, pure hashtable solutions, may not account
        for this use case and that hashtables do not allow duplicate keys.

      * Enables conversion of an array of values into a string, joined
        by choice of char/string, for value part of the key/value pair.

      * Enables addition of parameters only when a given constant/scriptblock evaluates to true.
.NOTES
    Like the base class, removing the port from ToString() output requires setting the
    port to -1. I don't care for the default behaviour but we'll stick with it for compatibility.
.EXAMPLE
    Add simple key/value pair.

    $Builder = [UriBuilderPro]::new('https://this.example.com')
    $Builder.AddParameter('one', 'two')
    $Builder.Parameters  # Display Parameters
    $Builder.Query       # Display Query

.EXAMPLE
    Add parameters based on predicate logic, either a constant
    or scriptblock that resolves to True/False.

    $Builder = [UriBuilderPro]::new('https://this.example.com')
    $exists = 'exists'
    $Builder.AddParameter('exists', $exists, $exists)  # Evals true and added
    $Builder.AddParameter('notExists', $notexists, $notexists)  # Evals false and not added
    $Builder.AddParameter('mayExist', $notexists, { $exists -eq 'notexists' })  # Evals false and not added
    $Builder.Parameters  # Display Parameters
    $Builder.Query       # Display Query

.EXAMPLE
    Add parameter with array values

    $Builder = [UriBuilderPro]::new('https://this.example.com')
    $Builder.AddParameter('foo', @('foo', 'fubar'))  # Implicit conversion of array value into multiple key=value pairs.
    $Builder.AddParameter('bar', @('bar', 'barfu'), $True, ',')  # Join array on string value. Pass $True just to satisfy overload.
    $Builder.Parameters  # Display Parameters
    $Builder.Query       # Display Query
#>
class UriBuilderPro : System.UriBuilder {
    [hashtable] $Parameters = @{}

    UriBuilderPro() : base() { }

    UriBuilderPro([string] $Uri) : base([string] $Uri) {}

    UriBuilderPro([uri] $uri) : base($args) {}

    UriBuilderPro([string] $schemeName, [string] $hostName) :
        base([string] $schemeName, [string] $hostName) {}

    UriBuilderPro([string] $scheme, [string] $hostname, [int] $portNumber) :
        base([string] $scheme, [string] $hostname, [int] $portNumber) {}

    UriBuilderPro([string] $scheme, [string] $hostname, [int] $port, [string] $pathValue) :
        base($args) {
            [string] $scheme, [string] $hostname, [int] $port, [string] $pathValue
        }

    UriBuilderPro([string] $scheme, [string] $hostname, [int] $port, [string] $path, [string] $extraValue) :
        base([string] $scheme, [string] $hostname, [int] $port, [string] $path, [string] $extraValue) {}

    AddParameter([string] $Key, [object] $Value) {
        if ($this.Parameters.ContainsKey($Key)) {
            throw [System.IO.InvalidDataException] "Cannot add duplicate key '$Key'"
        }
        $this.Parameters[$Key] = $Value
        $this.UpdateQuery()
    }

    AddParameter([string] $Key, [object] $Value, [string] $Join) {
        $this.AddParameter($Key, ($Value -join $Join))
    }

    AddParameter([string] $Key, [object] $Value, [object] $Predicate) {
        if ($null -ne $Predicate -and
            $Predicate.GetType().Name -eq "Scriptblock" -and
            $Predicate.InvokeReturnAsIs()
        ) {
            $this.AddParameter($Key, $Value)
        }
    }

    AddParameter([string] $Key, [object] $Value, [object] $Predicate, [string] $Join) {
        if ($null -ne $Predicate -and
            $Predicate.GetType().Name -eq "Scriptblock" -and
            $Predicate.InvokeReturnAsIs()
        ) {
            $this.AddParameter($Key, $Value, $Join)
        } elseif ($Predicate) {
            $this.AddParameter($Key, $Value, $Join)
        }
    }

    UpdateQuery() {
        $TempQuery = ''
        foreach($Param in $this.Parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
            # Regarding encoding of the parens, some markdown
            # parsers stop evaluating url syntax (ie [text](link) )
            # on the first occurence of a closing parens.
            # We don't want that so just encode them for safety.
            foreach ($Value in $Param.Value) {
                $TempQuery += "{0}={1}&" -f $Param.Key, [uri]::EscapeDataString($Value).Replace('(', '%28').Replace(')', '%29')
            }
        }
        # UriBuilder implicitly adds a leading ? mark when setting Query
        $this.Query = $TempQuery.TrimEnd('&')
    }
}
```